# make error during Homebrew Installing Apache 2.4 on Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-mavericks, homebrew

Having an issue using Homebrew to install Apache 2.4 on OSX 10.9. The tap I'm using is homebrew/apache (and also homebrew/dupes to provide apr and apr-util). Specifically, during the make install portion of installing httpd24 package, I see the following:

```
==> Installing httpd24
==> Downloading https://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.9.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/httpd24-2.4.9.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --enable-layout=Homebrew --enable-mods-shared=all --with-mpm=prefork --disable-unique-i
==> make
==> make install
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_vhost_alias.la mod_negotiation.la mod_dir.la mod_actions.la mod_speling.la mod_userdir.la mod_alias.la mod_rewrite.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

This is after Homebrew installs a couple of other deps, including apr, apr-util, (both of which give a warning about being keg-only) and pcre. After that I just get a notice about where to read about troubleshooting issues.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling homebrew and all packages, running brew doctor and brew update, and updating Xcode CLT to the latest version available through Apple Developer site. Not sure where to start with this, as it doesn't seem to be a common issue. Any ideas are would be greatly appreciated! I'm not very experienced with homebrew or compiling my own software, so I'm hoping this is just a stupid issue I don't even know to ask about.

Some other possibly relevant information:

```
==> Formula
Tap: homebrew/homebrew-apache
Path: /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-apache/httpd24.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
HEAD: 9f2190bcf95ba5eba60d364b8bc4667e1e564b48
CPU: 8-core 64-bit nehalem
OS X: 10.9.3-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 6.0.0.0.1.1404410606
X11: N/A
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/apr:/usr/local/opt/apr-util:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/apr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/apr-util/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/pcre/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.9
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/apr/bin:/usr/local/opt/apr-util/bin:/usr/local/opt/pcre/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue that I encounter as well, so when looking at the official site https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-apache, it mentioned that I have to symlink the related files that required with the following line:

```
sw_vers -productVersion | grep -E '^10\.([89]|10)' >/dev/null && bash -c "[ -d /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain ] && sudo -u $(ls -ld /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain | awk '{print $3}') bash -c 'ln -vs XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain' || sudo bash -c 'mkdir -vp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain/usr && for i in bin include lib libexec share; do ln -s /usr/${i} /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain/usr/${i}; done'"
```

After that I'm able to install the http24, hope it helps.